# What kind of coordinates are 38,40.1365N, 75,4.23933W?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a series of coordinates (e.g. 38,40.1365N, 75,4.23933W) that I cannot make sense of. These coordinates were with the pictures taken with iPhone 12. I need to know their type so that I can then convert them to standard coordinates accepted by ArcGIS.

Comment: [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) maybe, but with a comma for designing ° (degree)? And a decimal minute value. Would it make sense in your situation?

Comment: Yep makes sense now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mobile devices use WGS84 coordinates, and the coordinates might be displayed in different formats. One of them is DDM format. A comma for separating degree and minute, a dot for decimal. Your coordinates look like in that format.

DD: Decimal degrees. Ex: 38.2045 N
DDM: Degrees decimal minutes. Ex: 38° 40.1365' N
DMS: Degrees minutes seconds. Ex: 38° 40' 20" N

I think it is a very rare case. In many cases, it is represented as a DMS or DD.

A short Python script converting DDM string above to latitude and longitude values:

```py
def get_lat_lon(s):
    
    # split by comma
    l = s[1:-1].split(',')

    # get lat lon without direction
    lat = int(l[0]) + ( float(l[1][:-1]) / 60) # -1 for skipping direction letter
    lon = int(l[2]) + ( float(l[3][:-1]) / 60)
    
    # check cardinal direction letter
    if l[1][-1] in ['S', 's']: lat = -lat        
    if l[3][-1] in ['W', 'w']: lon = -lon
        
    return lat, lon

s = "(38,40.1365N, 75,4.23933W)"

lat, lon = get_lat_lon(s)
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like normal lat/lon:

```
38° 40.1365' N, 75° 04.23933’ W
```

DD MM SS:

```
38°40'08.2"N, 75°04'14.4"W
```

or Decimal Degrees:

```
38.668942, -75.070656
```